# How to force-stop a protected package?

Tags: adb, root, kill-process, superuser

I know the commands `am force-stop com.my.app` and `am kill com.my.app` that should stop a running app through the root terminal (using `su` command)

But know I have an app that refuse to stop after I kill her because she is a `protected package` And I get the following error:

> `java.lang.SecurityException: Cannot disable a protected package: com.my.app`

If you know how to kill a 'protected' app or to disable this protection I would like to get some help.

Comment: Have you found a solution?